# Passing Data Through AJAX Call Causes Failure

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am building a really simple AJAX call using Python/Django. I've never had issues with it before, but now I keep on getting a Not Found error if I ever put actual data in the AJAX call. Works fine if I place no data. I must be making a very obvious mistake that I just can't see.

In my code below, if I comment out the #test value it will work fine, so I know all the URLs are working correctly. It's just if I add any real data it fails (#product_id_notes is just filler, does not refer to an actual ID).

Can anyone help bail me out here? This has been driving my crazy for the last several hours.

My error:

```
Not Found: /admin/ajax/order_analysis
```

My html:

```
<button id = 'test1234'  >Submit</button>

<input id = "submit-order-analysis-url" type = 'hidden' value = ' {% url 'admin:order_analysis' %} '>

<div id = "test" value = "123">This is a test</div>
```

My code

```
$('#test1234').click(function() {
  
      var url = $('#submit-order-analysis-url').val();
      var data = {
                  'test':$('#test').val(),
                  'product_id':$('#product_id_notes').val()
                 }

      $.ajax({url: url, data: data})
        .done(function(data) {
          //do nothing
        })
        .fail(function() {
          //do nothing
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        });
      })
```

My Django View:

```
def order_analysis (request):
 from apps.seller.models.product import Product
 from django.core import serializers
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 print(request)
 from_day = request.GET.get('from-day')
 print("FROM DATY!: ",from_day)



 order_array = []
 try: 
   all_order_data = Order.objects.filter(created_at__year='2018', 
 created_at__month='01')
 # all_order_data = 
 Order.objects.filter(sampledate__gte=datetime.date(from_year, 
 from_month, from_day),
 #                             
 sampledate__lte=datetime.date(to_year,to_month, to_day))





for idv_order in all_order_data: 
  place_holder_dictionary ={}
  # print("123")
  place_holder_dictionary['order_id'] = str(idv_order.public_id)
  place_holder_dictionary['artisan_price'] = 
  str(idv_order.products_charge)
  place_holder_dictionary['product_id'] = str(idv_order.product.id)
  place_holder_dictionary['seller'] = 
  str(idv_order.product.seller.name)
  place_holder_dictionary['metric'] = 
  str(idv_order.product.metric_dimensions)
  place_holder_dictionary['photo'] = str(idv_order.product.photo)
  place_holder_dictionary['parent'] = 
  str(idv_order.product.parent_category)
  place_holder_dictionary['materials'] = 
  str(idv_order.product.materials_name_string) 
  place_holder_dictionary['name'] = str(idv_order.product.name) 


  print(idv_order.product.parent_category)

  order_array.append(place_holder_dictionary)

print("BEFORE ORDER")
order_array_data = json.dumps(order_array)
print("AFTER ORDER")
response = {'product_count': "Filler",
          'order_array': order_array_data,
          'page_obj':"Filler"
       }  
return JsonResponse(response)
```

except Exception as e:
print(e)
return HttpResponse(status=400)

Comment: If u don't send data do you get `reponse` correctly? And, ``request.GET.get('from-day')``??

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane That's correct. If I send no data, all works perfectly. I've never seen this type of thing happen before.

Comment: Do u pass `from-day`?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that function is never called regardless of what I pass. It only works if I pass nothing.

Comment: Can you confirm if u can reach into views.py or not by printing inside function

Comment: printing will work if I pass no data. But if data, then prints won't even work even as the initial line in the function. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221460/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-iampre409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is `value` is not valid attribute for `div`. But, you can do it with `data-*` attribute like:

```
<div id="test" data-value="123">This is a test</div>
```

In ajax:

```
var data = {
               'test':$('#test').attr('data-value'),
               'product_id':$('#product_id_notes').val()
           }
```

#### EDIT

In your post, `val()` is not working. But taking from the attribute instead of `val()` should work:

```
var data = {
               'test':$('#test').attr('value'),
               'product_id':$('#product_id_notes').val()
           }
```

## EDIT

The main problem was:

```
value = ' {% url 'admin:order_analysis' %} '
```

Your value should not contain space. So, do:

```
value = '{% url 'admin:order_analysis' %}'
```

*Note:- HTML is forgiving language, so later answer will also work. But, it is never the correct way and it violates *DTD*.

Comment: Thank you friend on the internet. I'll get that corrected. Still seems the problem exists. Even if I just put 'test':'abc' it will still fail though. So must be connected to something else.

Comment: How does it fail??? Do you get traceback in console from django?

Comment: In my logs I just get:  Not Found: /admin/ajax/order_analysis. This would suggest that it's URL problem, but if I just send no data, it works and triggers the function the url is pointing to. It's just baffling me right now.

Comment: Okay, show us `views.py` u r using for `/admin/ajax/order_analysis`

Comment: I've added the view to my question (will fix formatting). Thank you very much. The view works fine if I don't pass any data to it.